# can we use node js timer object in angular 4?

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

In my Angular application I need to make a http call in regular intervals of time (say every y mins) as long as the page is active and render the response on the screen.

Is it good to use `NodeJS.Timer` object to implement `setTimeout()`

or use `Observable.timer()`.

Comment: What does ***"execute a function for a particular period of time"*** mean?  A function executes for however long the JS interpreter takes to execute it.  You don't directly control that.  Do you mean start execution of a function at some particular time in the future?  Does this function run in the browser web page Javascript or on your server?

Comment: call a function (say every 10 mins). This function runs on the client side (browser).

Comment: Please edit your question to say (in your question), that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: call a function at regular intervals of time. It runs in the browser web page.

Comment: What is wrong with setInterval ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Observable.timer()` is a lot more useful for Angular

for example:

```
 const tick3$ = Observable.timer(100, 60000);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to execute a regular function every 10 minutes, you can just use plain Javascript for that:

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    // put your function code here
}, 10 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Or, if the function is already separately defined:

```
var timer = setInterval(myFunction, 10 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

> Is it good to use node js timer object to implement setTimeout()

It's really not clear what you mean by this question.  A nodejs timer object would be running things on the nodejs server, not on the client.  Since you said you want to run something in the browser web page, I presume you don't want a timer on nodejs to do that, but rather a timer in the web page as my example above shows.

---

Angular also has a wrapper around `setInterval()` called [`$interval()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) and it adds a few more features including a count and some angular specific functionality related to updating the view if the data changes.  If you want those angular specific features, you can use `$interval()`.  If not, then you can use either.